# Online broker available in Europe - to buy index funds or ETF with small investments

Tags: etf, investing, index-fund, broker, online-brokerage

So i am trying to start investing periodically some small amounts.
I am particularly interested in index funds or ETF.

I would like to be able buy, track, sell them, and etc online.
There are a lot of online brokers like : TD Ameritrade, etrade and etc. , but i cant seem to find the one that would allow to register fro Europe citizen, like from Denmark. (all the top ones require USA citizenship or etc).

Is there any like that at all ? If not - what other options there are to make such investments ?

Comment: Did you try TDWaterhouse, Selftrade ?

Comment: TDWaterhouse Seems to be be just UK Ireland and USA, but will check Selftrade - thanks. Any other options?

Answer (score 2):

Remember (danish) taxes, there are different rules depending on what you buy and how.

E.g. buying an ETF for free means is taxed as capital income (27%/42%). When done for pension means it is the PAL (15.3%).

There are danish investment funds that follows an index. You should be able to buy those, the yearly expenses are higher than an ETF but lower than active managed funds.
Spar Invest has several of those and there are banks that has some.

Answer (score 1):

A few ideas to get you started

- Go to your newsagent and buy the latest issue of some DIY investing magazine. You should get some commercial on the major players
- DumbCoder suggested tdwaterhouse. They have an [offshore service](http://int.tddirectinvesting.com/) (never tried them but the fees look high)
- [Saxobank](http://www.selectabroker.com/Denmark/) has a strong presence in the nordics
- Check this [page](http://dk.saxobank.com/). They seems to be comparing brokers in the different European countries. Not sure what to think about that their results. If I check for the UK I notice that a lot of the big guys are missing
- Use Google

Answer (score 0):

You should try [Nordnet](http://www.nordnet.dk). I think they should have a monthly saving plan on ETFs over there too.